# How do import a main Javascript file into other files?

Tags: javascript

I currently have separate Javascript code for each HTML page I have. I wrote some JavaScript code that I use frequently for HTTP requests to my Node server and it's my understanding that the code would run more efficiently if I moved this code to a central file and referenced it elsewhere. How can I import this file into another? Also, will doing so result in any more efficiency or will it just look cleaner?

Comment: If you want to stick with the way node.js does modules, I would suggest you look into using a module loader / packer.  There are a fair few, my personal favourite is `webpack`, but there is `browserfy`,  `systemjs` etc.  It then makes it trivial to share code between browser & nodejs..  That's what I call DRY.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easy import file to another file in `node.js`, but you want to import it in front-end, so you can only include a script file in an HTML page, not in another script file. You can write JavaScript which loads your "included" script into the same page using the following:

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = '/path/to/imported/script';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

Comment: @ATyshka, I think no, but this way you will follow DRY method (don't repeat yourself), I think, it's a good practice.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide won't the script be loaded asynchronously?

Comment: @ATyshka, no, this way it will be loaded synchronously

Comment: @ATyshka, did it help you, or you're searching for any other solution?